# Please help to untangle very difficult probability problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are three sacks filled with stones of three colores - black, white and grey.

**The first** sack contains 21% of black stones, 31% of white ones, the rest are grey.

**The second** sack contains 41% of whites, 41% of greys, the rest are black.

**The third** one contains 11% of greys, 31% of whites, the rest are black.

The second sack contains three times more stones than the first one.
The third sack contains two times more stones than the first one.

We take all stones from all sacks and put them into one empty sack. Then we draw a stone, and this stone happens to be white. What is the probability that this stone initially was from the third sack?
Could you please help me to write a proper formula at least?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there are 100 stones in first sack , then there will be respectively 300 and 200 stones in second and third stack. We mix them you can easily calculate there are 31,123 and 62 white stones came from sacks respectively in empty sack and now total 600 stones.Total white stones are 31+123+62=216, and from which 62 stones are from sack 3.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! Am I right? 216/600 is the probability of drawing a white ball from a common sack. And 62/200 is the probability of drawing a white ball from the third sack, then we want both these events to happen, and we get 216/600 * 62/200, this is around 11%.

Comment: You are right , but you did mistake last step.You see "White stone appears"  this event already happened so required probability is , 62/216.

Comment: You are confuse , see there is only one event is happening. If question were what is probability that you get a white stone from third sack. For better visualization assume on all stones there are number painted from which stack they came. So now you want a white stone with number 3 on it , such stones are 62 in 600 so probability will be 62/600.

Comment: Hope it cleared your confusion

Answer (score 0):

**Guide**:

Let the first sack contain $100$ stones, hence the second $300$ stones and the third $200$ stones.

Then how many white stones are there in total, and how many of these white stones are from the third sack?

Answer (score 0):

Using the conditional probability formula:
$$P(B_3|W)=\frac{P(B_3\cap W)}{P(W)}=\small{\frac{P(W)\cdot P(W|B_3)}{P(W)\cdot P(W|B_1)+P(W)\cdot P(W|B_2)+P(W)\cdot P(W|B_3)}}=\\
\frac{\frac26\cdot 0.31}{\frac16\cdot 0.31+\frac36\cdot 0.41+\frac26\cdot 0.31}=\frac{0.62}{0.31+1.23+0.62}=\frac{62}{216}\approx 0.287.$$